# OpenGL glTexImage2D memory issue

Tags: c, opengl

I'm loading a cubemap to create a skybox, everything is fine and the skybox renders properly with a correct texture application.

However, I decided to check my program safety with valgrind, Valgrind gives this error: http://pastebin.com/seqmXjyx

The line 53 in `sky.c` is:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, texture.width, texture.height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.pixels);

protoype:
void glTexImage2D( GLenum target,
              GLint level,
              GLint internalformat,
              GLsizei width,
              GLsizei height,
              GLint border,
              GLenum format,
              GLenum type,
              const GLvoid *pixels )
```

The texture width and height are unsigned int (1024x1024), and the pixels have bmp texture format.

It is correctly parsed for sure (as I said before, everything is rendered correctly, openGL returns no error, I only get this invalid write of 4 from valgrind).

(this invalid write appear every time I load a texture)

**So I read the man, and it made me even more confused, this is what I get from it:**

> `GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if width or height is less than 0 or greater than 2 + GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, or if either cannot be represented as 2^k +2 (border) for some integer value of k.`

`glGetError()` gives me `GL_NO_ERROR`, when I'm sending 1024*1024 as parameters, which is obviously not (2^k + 2)

I also read about the `border` parameter, which seems kind of useless for now the openGL I use, but could this be link to this overwrite?

Finally, as I said, everything works properly, but I would definitely like to know where are these invalids writes coming from.

The full project: https://github.com/toss-dev/minetoss

Comment: Try using [`GL_KHR_debug`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/KHR/debug.txt) if your GPU supports it. `glDebugMessageCallback` isn't too hard to set up. Texture borders are afaik deprecated.

Comment: I don't see anything incriminating with your code, but try swapping GL_BGR with GL_RGB.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, what do you mean genpfault (MCVE ?)

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which man page are you quoting? There are multiple man pages available, not all mapping to the same OpenGL version.

Anyways, the idea behind the `+ 2 (border)` is to have 2 multiplied by the value of `border`, which is in your case 0. So your code is just fine. `border` is a feature that is not supported by the latest GL versions and is therefore absent from the more recent man pages.

Now, back to your problem. The valgrind error is coming from within the GeForce GL driver, so unless you get access to the source, it's unlikely you'll get anywhere investigating it (you can try to contact the driver maintainers if you want... but may have a hard time getting any answer).

Comment: I cant post more link because of my reputatation, here is the man: opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml 

your answer seems ok to me, i didnt understood that `+ 2 (border)` meant `2 * border`, i'll try on another computer to see if it can come from my driver, thank you

Comment: You can get an error from within the driver if you pass in an invalid pointer to a GL function (like `glBufferData`) and the driver tries to dereference it.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Sure, you can. That doesn't mean it's the case here. And without source, it's not easy to check (though again, the code as written looks correct)

Comment: @toss: Also note that you are in an area where valgrind is prone to false alarms. Valgrind's picture of which address ranges are actually read- or writeable by the process is not complete. Valgrind assumes that the only way a process can get some address range of memory is through some standard kernel interfaces. But the opengl lib will interface heavily with the kernel part of the GPU driver, which can do lots of memory and/or I/O-mappings behind valgrind's back.